# Name of a conical solid object

Tags: geometry

Partitioning of a (right circular) cone with 60 degrees apex angle gives two half cones separated by an equilateral triangular interface. If one of the half-cone is rotated by 120 degrees and joined back with the other half-cone, then the resultant conical object exhibits 3 corners, 3 edges (2 lines, 1 curved), a single continuous conical surface with its apex point changing midway and two semi-circle faces. Does this interesting solid object have an established name?

Comment: Trisphericon, also known as $(3,1)$-icon. look at [here](http://www.mathias.org/steve/sphericons/series.htm) for some related shapes.

Comment: @achillehui: That comment sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solid object at hand is called Trisphericon, also known as $(3,1)$-icon.

It is a member of a family of shapes obtained in following manner:

> Start from a regular $n$-gon centered at origin, lying on $xy$-plane with 
>   $x$-axis passing through either one the vertex or one of the midpoints of an edge. Rotate the polygon with respect to $x$-axis to generate a solid of revolution.
>   Split the resulting solid into two pieces along the $xy$-plane, rotate the piece
>   above the $xy$-plane for an integer multiples of angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ and then glue the two pieces back together.

The most famous member of this family is the [Sphericon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphericon) which can be constructed start from a square. It was invented in $1979$ by David Hirsch as a device for generating a meander motion. It get the attention of math communities after Ian Stewart's $1999$ article "Cone with a Twist" appeared on Scientific American. 
Consult the wiki page about Sphericon for more historical details.

For the looks of some members of this family (in particular the one for Trisphericon), this [page](http://www.mathias.org/steve/sphericons/series.htm) by Steve will be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Achille Hui. The construction of this solid object is similar to the more familiarly known Sphericon, and is logical to consider it as an element of Sphericon series developed by [Steve](http://www.mathias.org/steve/sphericons/series.htm). However, the present object constructed from a Cone is more elementary compared to the Sphericon constructed from Bicone. I propose a name '*Chirocone*', the greek phrase 'Chiro' suggesting that the cone has acquired right/left handedness depending on the type of rotation (+/- 120 degrees) of the half-cone before joining. The *Chirocone* solid can roll smoothly from one semi-circle face to the other and the entire conical surface covers the ground. The Sphericon solid is distinctly unique as it can keep rolling over and over again, but it is a non-chiral object. The alternate name '*Chirocone*' captures the solid object property in a simple way, but it is etymologically a '*Trisphericon*' belonging to the Sphericon series.